# Sorting Pandas Dataframe column(contains date value) in ascending order

Tags: python, pandas

I was able to sort the column containing date values in descending order, but not in ascending order. Done a lot of research, but was not able to find a solution.

This is what I have so far:

```
unique_dates_df.sort_values(['Date'],ascending=[False])
```

I gave `ascending= false` as well as `true`, but both of them are sorting it in descending order

Comment: Are you sure that the date column is in datetime format ? Could you check the dtype ? If not try doing pd.to_datetime(df[your column] )

Answer (score 0):

Maybe forget assign output:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2017-04-03', periods=10)
unique_dates_df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': rng, 'a': range(10)})  
print (unique_dates_df)
        Date  a
0 2017-04-03  0
1 2017-04-04  1
2 2017-04-05  2
3 2017-04-06  3
4 2017-04-07  4
5 2017-04-08  5
6 2017-04-09  6
7 2017-04-10  7
8 2017-04-11  8
9 2017-04-12  9

unique_dates_df = unique_dates_df.sort_values(['Date'],ascending=False)
print (unique_dates_df)
        Date  a
9 2017-04-12  9
8 2017-04-11  8
7 2017-04-10  7
6 2017-04-09  6
5 2017-04-08  5
4 2017-04-07  4
3 2017-04-06  3
2 2017-04-05  2
1 2017-04-04  1
0 2017-04-03  0
```

Or use parameter `inplace=True`:

```
unique_dates_df.sort_values(['Date'],ascending=False, inplace=True)
print (unique_dates_df)
        Date  a
9 2017-04-12  9
8 2017-04-11  8
7 2017-04-10  7
6 2017-04-09  6
5 2017-04-08  5
4 2017-04-07  4
3 2017-04-06  3
2 2017-04-05  2
1 2017-04-04  1
0 2017-04-03  0
```